how to conect TNC FlipBook - PDF viewer for WordPress does not read PDF files from AWS S3?
cannot read the plugin even with CORS permissions and also disabling the ucket's "block all public access"
The plugin cannot read the pdf files stored in AWS S3, the CORS permissions on the bucket are as follows:
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*",
            "rango",
            "Authorization"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE",
            "GET"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "https://midominio.pe",
            "https://subdominio.midominio.pe",
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "x-amz-server-side-encryption",
            "x-amz-request-id",
            "x-amz-id-2",
            "Accept-Ranges",
            "Content-Encoding",
            "Content-Length",
            "Content-Range"
        ],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]

The "blocking all public access" of the bucketh is also deactivated, despite this it cannot read, does anyone know how I could fix this problem.
